# How Do I make an Elm-UI element respond to pressing "Enter"

Tags: elm, elm-ui

I need to make my app send a message when Enter is pressed. I have an element like:

```
Input.text [] { onChange = UpdateText, text = model.text, placeholder=Nothing }
```

How can I make it submit when enter is pressed?

Note: Q/A copied from the [Elm-Slack](https://elmlang.slack.com/archives/C4F9NBLR1/p1566319684031800) for findability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [Elm-UI docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/elm-ui/latest/Element-Input) .

Basically, you define a function that sends a `msg` when the Enter Key is pressed and embed that into your `view` function:

```
onEnter : msg -> Element.Attribute msg
onEnter msg =
    Element.htmlAttribute
        (Html.Events.on "keyup"
            (Decode.field "key" Decode.string
                |> Decode.andThen
                    (\key ->
                        if key == "Enter" then
                            Decode.succeed msg

                        else
                            Decode.fail "Not the enter key"
                    )
            )
        )
```

Then embed it into the attributes of an element in your view:

```
Input.text
    [ onEnter EnterWasPressed ]
    { onChange = UpdateText
    , text = model.text
    , placeholder = Nothing
    }
```

Ellie Link (From docs): https://ellie-app.com/5X6jBKtxzdpa1

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to leave out. I wonder why.

Comment: What if I don't want the onChange being triggered? Since the onChange is mandatory in elm-ui, I still need a Message tag which do nothing in the `update` function?  weird.